# incorrect test execution queue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
// file.spec.js
describe('[test]', () => {
    it('first', () => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it('second', () => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

in `file.spec.js` -> `ctrl + S` (first save):

```
[test]
   first
   second
```

in `file.spec.js` -> `ctrl + S` (second save):

```
[test]
   second
   first
```

Is it normal that the test execution queue is broken?

**UPD:0.0.1**

part `package.json` with version libraries-
part `package.json` with version libraries-
part `package.json` with version libraries-
part `package.json` with version libraries-

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.9",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.0.0-1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: no.. its because of jasmine version.. what is your jasmine version btw.

Comment: try to use jasmine version 2.3.4..

Comment: @TraxX update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I'm using the latest version of `jasmine-core` and I also found that the execution was not in order and after a day or two, I found out the it was because of the jasmine version. Now my jasmine version is 2.3.4 and it executes the tests in order. There is a downside to this approach.

You can't use the other benefits of future versions like `toBeGreaterThanOrEqual` or other `availableMatchers` that jasmine provides out-of-the-box. Although you can create your own jasmine matchers, there are more other functionalities that they can add. Who knows what are those right?

So if you want your tests to be in order then feel free to use version 2.3.4 (I'm using this one along with karma-spec-reporter and tweak a bit) or if not, you can use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your test cases should be independent. Their results should not depend on the execution order

Answer (score 0):

Update package

> karma-jasmine:"^2.0.1"

and update your karma.conf.js.

```
client:{
  jasmine: {
    random: false // disable the random running order
  }
},
```